# Why do React event handlers behave differently when receiving arguments?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

With the following code, every time I click the button, "I was clicked" is outputted to the console, as expected.

```
function handleClick() {
    console.log("I was clicked")
}

function App() {
    return (
        <div>
            <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/200/100"/>
            <br />
            <br />
            <button onClick={handleClick}>Click me</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

However, if I change handleClick to take in a parameter, the output is shown upon page load and any additional clicks don't produce additional output.

```
function handleClick(test) {
    console.log(test + "I was clicked")
}

function App() {
    return (
        <div>
            <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/200/100"/>
            <br />
            <br />
            <button onClick={handleClick("hello: ")}>Click me</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Why does the simple act of including a parameter change the behavior, here? I suspect it has to do with the event handler not passing along the event object in the second scenario, while automatically being passed in the first scenario, but I'm not sure what properties of the event object would be causing this behavior.

Comment: because in javascript, `()` right after a function means to call it immediately, you can bind the function: `handleClick.bind(this, "hello: ")` or you can wrap the function in another one: `() => {handleClick("Hello: ")}`. If you choose to bind, keep in mind to bind the correct scope (the first parameter is the scope, in my example, `this`)

Answer (score 1):

if you use () after the function; it means that the function executes. To assign values with this syntax, you can easily use

```
onPress={handleClick.bind(this, ...args)}
```

With this syntax, we bind the this of the current scope to the function and we did not execute it while assigning parameters. The way of assigning parameters and invoking the function immediately would be

```
handleClick.call(this, ...args)
```